# Querying Twitter JSON File in HBase

Tags: arrays, json, twitter, struct, hbase

I have successfully downloaded twitter data through flume directly into HBase table containing one column family and all of the data is stored in one column like this

> hbase(main):005:0> scan 'tweet'
>     ROW
>     default00fbf898-6f6e-4b41-aee8-646efadfba46
>     COLUMN+CELL
>     column=data:pCol, timestamp=1454394077534, value={"extended_entities":{"media":[{"display_url":"pic.twitter.com/a7Mjq2daKZ","source_user_id":2987221847,"type":"photo"....

Now i want to access structs and arrays through HBase like we can access then in Hive. I have tried googling the issue but still clue less. Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

You can't query display_url , source_user_id or another json fields in hbase directly. You should use a document store nosql db like mongodb.

Comment: What about creating Hive external table on Hbase tweet table and then querying it from Hive?

Comment: if you make a table from json data, you will not have json data anymore, so you can query it from hbase or hive or apache phoenix (sql on hbase) . I mean you will have cloumns as displayurl, source_user_id and so on, so this is queryable on both hbase and hive. But you can't have nested data structure like a json document.